# How to add Bootstrap to React app and use classes inside

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

Can someone please explain how to add bootstrap to react app and how to use them inside react components since we can not add CDN links and "class" attribute inside a react app. Would you kindly please explain how to use bootstrap components inside react app. This will really helpful for me since i'm a very beginner to react developer..

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/ check this link

Comment: if you need to use only css, add `bootstrap.min.css` to you project folder. Then import it into `App.js`. After importing you can use bootstrap class inside your app like this `<div className='row'></div>`

Comment: there are 2 dependencies which I was used in my different projects 1.) react-bootstrap or 2.) reactstrap get any of one and try to ride.

Comment: Thanks for your help Delowar Hosain ..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

```
     1. install react-bootstrap

                npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap


     2. import css file in your index.js or app.js

                import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

             <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
              crossorigin="anonymous"
             />

      3. import components like

                import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

You can use normal bootstrap classes like `className="row"`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use bootstrap directly in react application instead you can use [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) which contains the bootstrap components.

Example of using reactstrap inside react

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Button color="danger">Danger!</Button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want standard Bootstrap

1. install

```css
npm i bootstrap
```

2. import in **App.js**

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import "bootstrap"; // <-- JS File
```